# How to display SVG Templates in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, svg

I am trying to display an SVG Template in my SwiftUI app.

So, I have a `var svgTemplate: String` variable in my SwiftUI App that contains an SVG Template string, an example is displayed below

```
"<svg width=\"1024\" height=\"440\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:
                         <!-- more data --> 
xml:space=\"preserve\" text-anchor=\"start\" font-family=\"
Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif\" font-size=\"24\" id=\"svg_1\" y=\"151.52317\" 
x=\"93.43789\" stroke-width=\"0\" fill=\"#000000\">This is sample svg template
</text>\n </g>\n</svg>"
```

Now, I want to render this SVG Template in my SwiftUI app, but I cannot figure out a way to do so.

I tried to convert my `svgTemplate` to a `base64StringImage` so that I can display a `base64StringImage` by extending the `Image View`, but I cannot find a way to convert my `svgTemplate` to a `base64StringImage`.

The other way I tried was just to display the `svgTemplate` but that was unsuccessful as well.

Any kind of solution would be helpful.

Thank you in advance! :)